# Summing pandas dataframe time series by day

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am reading in a csv file of time series data into a pandas DataFrame and extracting the two relevant columns as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Stuart\Documents\SPYDER\Joint_Strat.csv', index_col=0)

df2 = df['weighted ret']

df2.head()

date
02/01/2007    0.002432
02/01/2007    0.001216
02/01/2007    0.001216
03/01/2007    0.000597
03/01/2007    0.000448
Name: weighted ret, dtype: float64
```

I want to sum the 'weighted ret' column by days, so that each date is shown just once with the corresponding returns summed for that day. I tried the following:

```
df2 = df2.resample('D',how='sum')
```

But get the error:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex
```

So I then tried to change the index to a date time by:

```
import dateutil

df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
```

and then run

```
df2 = df2.resample('D',how='sum')
```

again.

It seems to run but then when I print out

```
df2.head(10)
```

I get the following:

```
2007-01-02   -0.002244
2007-01-03    0.001009
2007-01-04         NaN
2007-01-05         NaN
2007-01-06   -0.000732
2007-01-07         NaN
2007-01-08    0.002016
2007-01-09         NaN
2007-01-10    0.001267
2007-01-11   -0.0012
```

This is not correct as I have values for the dates that are showing NaN, and in fact the figures that do show are not the correct values for the sum of each of the intraday returns.

I should imagine this should be simple to do, but I just can not get it to work properly and don't know where to go from here. Could someone please suggest where I am going wrong? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to group on the index of the Series as follows:

```
df2.groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Answer (score -1):

DataFrame.resample() for daily samples with how="sum"